# List (Generic) using jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I have a webmethod in asp.net project i wanna pass a listview in jquery ajax method but i dont now how can i detect elements of listview and using them.folowing code is my c# code.bt i need jquery code

```
if (ck != null)
{
      reqnum[0, 0] = "@RequestingBranchID";
      reqnum[0, 1] = ck["BranchID"];
      reqnum[1, 0] = "@ProviderBranchID";
      reqnum[1, 1] = customer.ToString();
      DataTable dt = SqlCommands.FillData(out OutStatus, out OutMessage, "BSD.SW_Boxes_StockOfProviderAndRequestingBranch", CommandType.StoredProcedure, reqnum);
      List<DataRow> rows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();
      int x=rows.Count;
      return rows;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to pass values selected in listview using jquery?

Comment: no i wanna pass datatable via web method to jquery ajax but i used list

Comment: you want to pass the list from your c# code to some javascript function ?? or you want the opposite??

Comment: maybe this can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377117/how-to-correctly-reload-data-from-web-method-using-jquery-datatables

Comment: i wanna pass list from my c# to javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok let's say that you have a `DataTable` and you want to pass the results of this `DataTable` to some JavaScript to display the results using `Ajax`. So first step is that we need to convert these results into [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format. you can the following method::

```
public string GetJson(DataTable dt)
{
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row = null;

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns) {
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }
    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```

the next step is to parse the result [JSON](http://www.json.org/) string in JavaScript and i guess this the easy part. You can just check this question to find out how to parse [JSON](http://www.json.org/) string into objects [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object) .If u want know more tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) to serialize your datatable to JSON. Then call the webmethod using ajax.

In server side,

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string GetList(int branchID, string customer)
{
    // do your code here
    reqnum[0, 0] = "@RequestingBranchID";
    reqnum[0, 1] = branchID;
    reqnum[1, 0] = "@ProviderBranchID";
    reqnum[1, 1] = customer;
    DataTable dt = SqlCommands.FillData(out OutStatus, out OutMessage, "BSD.SW_Boxes_StockOfProviderAndRequestingBranch", CommandType.StoredProcedure, reqnum);
    if(dt!=null)
    {
          return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
    }
    else{
        //return "[]"; 
    }
}
```

Then in script call your method and pass the parameters for the method.

```
$(function(){});
    $('#myButton').click(function() {
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url: "YourPage.aspx/GetList",
            data: "{'branchID':" + branchID + ",'customer':" + customer + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var jsonResult = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                // do your client side code here
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Note: If you are not using a webservice/writing the method in your code behind, use `[ScriptService]` decorator before your class and include the following namespaces.

```
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Services;
```